# Splunk field extractor unable to extract all values

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I want to extract 4 values out of one field, called msg, from a Splunk query; and the msg is in the form of:

```
msg: "Service call successful k1=v1 k2=v2 k3=v3 k4=v4 k5=v5 something else can be ignored"
```

keys are always static but values are not, for instance, v2 could be XXX or XXYYZZ; similarly possible values for v3 just have unpredictable length.

I query to get some sample results and hope to use Field Extractor to generate a regex, but the regex generated can't get all the values out and I guess it's probably because values are not having the same length?

Do I need to change my logging format by separating each key=value using a common? Or I am not using the field extractor correctly?

[Update1]: A few sample data:

`msg:Service call successful k1=XXX k2=BBBB k3=Something I made up k4=YYYNNN k5=do not need to retrieve this value`

`msg:Service call successful k1=SSSSSS k2=AAA k3=This could contain space and comma, like this one k4=YYYNNM k5=can be ignored`

I could change the logging format if it makes easier to query and extract fields. Will adding a separator like dot or pipe help?

Answer (score 2):

*Normally* Splunk will pull key-value pairs out automatically

However, when it doesn't, go try your regular expression(s) on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9HgTJl/1) - the field extractor is often a good[ish] *start*, but rarely creates efficient (or complete) regular expressions

An inline version of this would be as follows (presuming the "value" half of the key-value pair is contiguous characters):

```
| rex field=_raw "k1=(?<k1>\S+)\s+k2=(?<k2>\S+)\s+k3=(?<k3>\S+)\s+k4=(?<k4>\S+)\s+k5=(?<k5>\S+)"
```

*Normally* I prefer to do sequential [`rex`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/rex) calls, in case something's out of order or missing, but if your data's *consistent*, this will work

Once you have it the way you want it, update your [`props.conf`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Admin/Propsconf) and [`transforms.conf`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Admin/Transformsconf) as appropriate for the [sourcetype](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Data/Createsourcetypes)

### EDIT for updated sample data / comment response:

```
...
| rex field=_raw "k3=(?<k3>.+)\s+k4="
| rex field=_raw "k4=(?<k4>.+)\s+k5="
...
```

Comment: Will this work for values that have space in it? e.g. k3=hello world.

Comment: @dragonfly02 - no, hence my qualifier of "contiguous characters" :). Give us some better sample data, and we can help improve the rex to be more flexible :)

Comment: Thanks. I added some sample data. I can change the data format if it will make extraction easier. Also will sequential `rex` call make this easier? The key order is static btw; it's just the values vary by length.

Comment: see update to use sequential `rex` calls :)